# automatically releasing objects allocated by an external api

Tags: c++, memory-management, c++11

I have a Visual Studio 2013 C++11 program where I need to use an API that allocates a number of character buffers in an array:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    char* names[10] = {};
    unsigned int count = _countof(names);
    some_external_api_to_get_values(count, names, &count);
    // do something with the names array...
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
        release_objects(names[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

I would prefer to have the objects automatically released on destruction. So I added this class, but I'm missing something that will allow the compiler to convert between this class and the char** type it expects.

```
template<typename T>
class release_objects_on_destruction : private boost::noncopyable
{
public:
    explicit release_objects_on_destruction(T* p) : p_(p) { };
    release_objects_on_destruction() : p_(nullptr) { };
    ~release_objects_on_destruction() { if (p_) release_objects(p_); };
    T** operator&() { return &p_; };
    operator T*() const { return p_; };    
    operator const T*() const { return p_; };
private:
    T* p_;
};

int main( int argc, char* argv[])
{
    release_objects_on_destruction<char> names[10];
    unsigned int count = _countof(names);
    // error C2664: 'int some_external_api_to_get_values(unsigned int,char**,unsigned int*)' : cannot convert argument 2 from 'release_objects_on_destruction<char> [10]' to 'char**'
    some_external_api_to_get_values(count, names, &count);
    return 0;
}
```

What conversion operator am I missing?

Comment: You're applying the `&` operator to *an array* of `release_objects_on_destruction`, so your custom `operator&` will not be called.

Comment: Make a wrapper class around the resources and use good old RAII.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work because your API is on the wrong level. You need to encapsulate both the external_api call and the release_objects call into the same object. That's why your current wrapper is failing.

```
class api_wrapper {
    static const object_count = 10;
    std::array<char*, object_count> objects;
    unsigned count = object_count;
public:
    api_wrapper() {
        some_external_api_to_get_values(count, objects.data(), &count);
    }
    // example accessors
    char** data() { return objects.data(); }
    unsigned count() { return count; }

    api_wrapper(api_wrapper&& other)
        : objects(other.objects), count(other.count)
    {
        other.count = 0;
    }
    api_wrapper(const api_wrapper&) = delete;
    ~api_wrapper() {
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
            release_objects(objects[i]);
    }
};
```